# Will a generic carbon filter reduce radon in my water?

Tags: water, filter, radon

The title pretty much says it all. [image: Generic carbon filter]

Will a carbon filter like this help reduce radon in my water?

Answer (score 0):

no it will not - carbon filters are incapable of filtering radon from water or air

Answer (score 0):

Granular activated carbon can remove radon from water. As to that specific filter, you would need to check with the manufacturer or consult the packaging/instructions.

http://extension.psu.edu/natural-resources/water/drinking-water/water-testing/pollutants/reducing-radon-in-drinking-water